# Create a report wizard fails in ArcGIS 10 (win7 x64) - but works in ArcGIS 10 (winxp 32bit)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, reports

The report creation wizard will not launch for me when I try accessing it from both the View menu and from an attribute table.  I am able to open a saved report template though.  This seems like it is a Windows 7 issue since the wizard does launch under Windows XP.  Or it could be a 64bit vs 32bit issue.

This has been reported in the ArcGIS blog [Working with Reports in ArcMap, Part I-Getting Started](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/01/working-with-reports-in-arcmap-part-i-getting-started/).

I actually ended up doing the task using Mail Merge in Word 2007.  It was so easy to format it together from an exported attribute table - I'd definitely do this again, even if I could get the report wizard to work.

Comment: Are you running on the same machine or is there any other difference between the XP and Win7? For example 32bit/64bit?

Comment: good question, I should have mentioned that before.  XP is 32bit, Win7 is 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on Windows 7, so this suggests it is something specific to your environment and not a bug in the software.

[image]

Not too sure on how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Would you look at that... hmm... here I was thinking it was OS specific.  Thank you for trying it out.

Comment: is your version of Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64.  Although I can also vouch that it works on 32 as well.